# geth --rinkeby can not find peers

Tags: geth

I want to run a Rinkeby full node. That is my startup script for geth:

```
geth    --rinkeby \
        --cache=2048 \
        --http --http.port=8545 --http.addr=127.0.0.1 --http.api=eth,web3,net,personal --http.corsdomain "*" \
        --syncmode=fast
```

geth starts but obviously it cannot connect to any peers. I get the following debug output:

```
INFO [08-05|07:03:02.696] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=137 static=0
INFO [08-05|07:03:12.832] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=180 static=0
INFO [08-05|07:03:23.506] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=81  static=0
INFO [08-05|07:03:35.003] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=198 static=0
INFO [08-05|07:03:45.042] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=105 static=0
INFO [08-05|07:03:56.216] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=96  static=0
INFO [08-05|07:04:06.978] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=118 static=0
INFO [08-05|07:04:17.244] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=110 static=0
INFO [08-05|07:04:27.273] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=189 static=0
INFO [08-05|07:04:39.046] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=81  static=0
```

It is running already for more than 12 hours like this. I also tried to stop the firewall, but this doesn't change anything.

Here is output of geth version:

```
Geth
Version: 1.9.19-unstable
Git Commit: 8e7bee9b56763e94c06e597bf968838e7ea2d03b
Git Commit Date: 20200727
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [65 64 63]
Go Version: go1.13.14
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/lib64/go/1.13
```

What can I do, that geth finds other peers?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you update to the latest stable version `1.10.x` and still having the discovery issue. Try running the node using `--v5disc` option which enables the experimental [RLPx V5](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md) (Topic Discovery) mechanism.

**Edit**:

Also, not having the discovery port setup correctly `30303` can result in nodes not being able to find peers.
Make sure, no more than one more process is trying to listen on that port.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your geth version is unstable. Try to install the latest stable version. This should solve the problem.